# How to register mouse hover event over Visual Studio menu item?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, envdte, vsix, vspackage

I'm writing VSIX plugin. I've created an icon on Visual Studio standard toolbar. My custom command is attached to it:

```
var mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
var commandId = new CommandID(GuidList.guidSthCmdSet, PkgCmdIDList.cmdidSth);
command = new OleMenuCommand(DoSomething, commandId);
mcs.AddCommand(command);
```

If I click on this icon, the `DoSomething` function invokes. What I need to do now is to run other function, while the cursor of my mouse is over the toolbar icon. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, this is not possible...

Comment: I suppose that there is no obvious method but not even any hacks ? Maybe by the usage of COM objects.. basically I'm in trouble because at current stage I don't even know what kind of information I need to search for, to start implement any workaround.

Comment: Can you explain what you´re trying to achieve; maybe there is a better (even simpler) solution.

Comment: I was trying to write an extension, which was aware of some state changes across multiple instances of Visual Studios. If such change was done in one VS, I needed such an information to be reflected in another VS, inside the tooltip over particular button. I thought I need an event which could fire while mouse cursor is over the button to get and show fresh info. I found simple workaround. Just wrote an internal thread which works as a pooling mechanism. It just sucks some fresh stuff periodically and updates the tooltip (each second - quite enough for a user to change from one VS to another).